# Windows Docker Dockerfile COPY file inside folder

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile to copy a file to container, I'm using Windows 10. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY /target/myfile.java /
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/target/myfile.java" not found: not found
```

I already tried `//target//myfile.java`, `\\target\\myfile.java`, `\target\myfile.java`, `target/myfile.java`, `target\myfile.java` but none of them worked.

If I put the myfile.java on the same directory of Dockerfile and use `COPY myfile.java /` works without problem. So the problem is to copy a file inside a folder. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Dockerfile locally and it built fine with the following directory structure:

```
Project
│   Dockerfile
│
└───target
│   │   myfile.java
```

I built it from the 'Project' directory with the following command:

```
docker build . -t java-test
```

---

I could only reproduce the error when the Docker server couldn't find the 'myfile.java', i.e. using the following directory structure:

```
Project
│   Dockerfile
│
└───target
│   └───target
│       └───myfile.java
```

---

So your dockerfile looks fine, just make sure you build it from the right directory with the correct build context and the file is stored in the correct place locally